# Error while compile a Parser rule

Tags: parsing, computer-science, antlr4, lexer

The code for parser that I had:

```
funcall: ID LB exp? RB ;

exp: funcall | INTLIT ;
```

Then my assignment requires that I need to do like this for the "funcall":

> An invocation expression is a function call which starts with an identifier followed by “(“ and “)”. A nullable comma-separated list of expressions might be appeared between “(“ and “)” as a list of arguments.

And for the "exp", it must follow the Precedence and Associativity:

[image: Precedence and Associativity]

So I tried to write my code like this to match the requirements (I'm not so sure the order of literals after "funcall" because it's not mentioned in the assignment):

```
funcall: ID LB (exp (COMMA exp)*)? RB ;

exp
: LB exp RB
| LSB exp RSB
| <assoc=right> (SUB | NOT) exp
| exp op = (DIV | MUL | MODUL) exp
| exp op = (ADD | SUB) exp
| exp op = (LT | LTOE | GT | GTOE) exp
| exp op = (EQUAL | NOEQUAL) exp
| exp AND exp
| exp OR exp
| <assoc=right> exp ASSIGN exp
| funcall
| (INTLIT | FLOATLIT)
| (TRUE | FALSE)
| ID
| STRINGLIT ;
```

But then I got the error like this, which prevent me from using notation * with "(COMMA exp)" or even "exp" itself:

[image: Compiling Error]

Here is code for class ASTGeneration where I get error:

> override def visitFuncall(ctx:FuncallContext) = CallExpr(ctx.ID.getText,if (ctx.exp == null) List() else List(visit(ctx.exp).asInstanceOf[Expr]))

This is my lexer code that involved:

```
LB: '(' ;

RB: ')' ;

LP: '{' ;

RP: '}' ;

SEMI: ';' ;

LSB: '[' ;

RSB: ']' ;

COMMA: ',' ;

ADD: '+' ;

SUB: '-' ;

MUL: '*' ;

DIV: '/' ;

OR: '||' ;

AND: '&&' ;

NOT: '!' ;

NOEQUAL: '!=' ;

EQUAL: '==' ;

MODUL: '%' ;

ASSIGN: '=' ;

LT: '<' ;

LTOE: '<=' ;

GT: '>' ;

GTOE: '>=' ;

TRUE: 'true' ;

FALSE: 'false' ;

INTLIT: [0-9]+ ;

FLOATLIT: INTLIT DOT INTLIT ;
fragment DOT: '.' ;

ID: [_a-zA-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]* ;

STRINGLIT: '"' ('\\' [bfrnt'"\\] | ~[\b\f\r\n\t'"\\])*; '"' ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Anyone can tell me what was wrong in my parser code (now I'm wondering about my "exp" could lead to the error in "funcall") and which way should I fix it. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your generated code. Since you have more than one `expr` in your `funcall` rule the `expr` member in your funcall context class is not a single node, but a node (context) list, filled with `expr` parse contexts as they come in during parsing.

Comment: I think I may check back my code since your comment reminds me about the implicit connection between them.